# Find out the identity of the person that called you

Tags: phone, identity

I once heard that if a number that you don't know called you, you can access a website (that I don't remember now) that will call the number and make a recording of what the person said and send it to you. Is it legal? Or can I find a better way to find out the person identity?

Answer (score 4):

Why are you assuming it is a "person" who called you?

Most people will just Google the number - typically if this is one of those spam callers you will find out some information about them on discussion groups.

I am not sure why it would be illegal to search *publicly* available information about a phone number that called you.

Comment: Recording a call without permission is illegal in some states/countries. Not sure that's what the mystery site does, but it might.

Comment: Agree with you @NeilSmithline on the recording front.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it isn't a spam caller. The number can't be find on google.

Comment: @YazadKhambata When I've asked if it's legal, I was referring at the part with recording the call.